# Store the base address of 3 basic blocks address of a 3D array into an array pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

Each element of a 3D array is a 2D array. Once the 3D array is declared, a is treated as pointer to zeroth element of the array. Hence a[0] i.e *(a+0) or *a gives the zeroth element which is a 2D array. We know that on mentioning a 2D array we get its base address. So I want to store the base address of 0th, 1st and 2nd 2D array base addresses to the array pointer ptr1, but since I am storing the address of a block of 3 int's in each ptr1[0], ptr1[1], ptr1[2], I need to typecast it, but I don't know how?

The problem is the typecasting in  int *ptr1[3]={a[0],a[1],a[2]};. 
The error I am getting is:

> **cannot convert 'int (*)[3]' to 'int*' in initialization**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    static int a[3][3][3]={{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
                          {2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18},
                          {3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27}};                                
    static int* ptr[]={
                       a[0][0],a[0][1],a[0][2],
                       a[1][0],a[1][1],a[1][2],
                       a[2][0],a[2][1],a[2][2]};
    int *ptr1[3]={a[0],a[1],a[2]};
        printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<=8;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",*ptr2);
        ptr2++;

    }

    printf("\n");

    for(i=0;i<=2;i++)
    {
        printf("%d",*(ptr1[i]));
    }


    printf("\n");

    for(i=0;i<=8;i++)
    {
        printf("%d",*ptr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What you get as error or undesired output ?

Comment: Clearly, you are not showing us what you're compiling.  This `a[2[0],a[2][1],a[2][2]};` is missing a close square bracket after the first 2. There's also a stray open paren in the `int *ptr1[3]` initializer.

Comment: There's an open parenthesis and (a) no closing parenthesis, or, more relevantly, (b) no need for the open parenthesis.

Comment: Given that the `int *ptr[] = { a[0][0], … };` is OK, there's no way that `int *ptr1[3] = { a[0], … };` can also be OK.  The initializers are of different types but the arrays are of the same basic type (array of pointers to `int`).  Your `printf()` is also trying to print a pointer with the format for an `int`.

Comment: Don't show the code you aren't interested in.  Please read how to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — two names and links for the same basic idea.

Comment: int (*ptr1[3])[3]={a[0],a[1],a[2]}; can you try this ? . note that a decays in to a pointer to two dimensional array and,*a to one dimensional one and **a to the address of the object and ***a gives the value of the object. so the array you are trying to store is pointer to one dimensional arrays

Comment: @bare_metal i tried that ..and its working but can u tell me in a simple way what you want to say because  i am beginners in c language

Comment: @bare_metal But can u tell me  
int (*ptr1[3])[3]={a[0],a[1],a[2]}; is this a pointer to array or array pointer? i am bit confuse

Comment: please see the following links to figure it out. http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html. and cdecl.org ( as pointed out by  WhozCraig).  ptr1 is an array 3 of pointer to array 3 of int please see http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/languages/fortran/append-c.html for arrays and pointers in c

Answer (score 2):

It is gruesome, but this code compiles cleanly and runs sanely:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    static int a[3][3][3] =
    {
        { { 1, 2, 3, }, {  4,  5,  6, }, {  7,  8,  9, }, },
        { { 2, 4, 6, }, {  8, 10, 12, }, { 14, 16, 18, }, },
        { { 3, 6, 9, }, { 12, 15, 18, }, { 21, 24, 27, }, },
    };
    static int *ptr[] =
    {
        a[0][0], a[0][1], a[0][2],
        a[1][0], a[1][1], a[1][2],
        a[2][0], a[2][1], a[2][2],
    };
    int (*ptr1[3])[] =  // an array of 3 pointers to arrays of int
    {
        a[0], a[1], a[2],
    };
    int **ptr2 = ptr;

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", (*ptr2)[0]);
        ptr2++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", (*ptr1[i])[0]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1
4
7
2
8
14
3
12
21
1
2
3
```

Compilation:

```
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
    -Wold-style-definition -Werror mess.c -o mess
```

Interesting quirk: you can write any of the following declarations for the `ptr1` and get clean working code:

```
int (*ptr1a[ ])[3] = { a[0], a[1], a[2], };
int (*ptr1b[3])[3] = { a[0], a[1], a[2], };
int (*ptr1c[3])[ ] = { a[0], a[1], a[2], };
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    printf("%d = %d = %d\n", (*ptr1a[i])[0], (*ptr1b[i])[0], (*ptr1c[i])[0]);
```

Comment: Can u Explain me how ?  int (*ptr1[3])[] =
    {
        a[0], a[1], a[2],
    }; what does it represent whether it is a "Pointer to an array or it is simply a array pointer"

Comment: @AbhishekWalter [**see this**](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int+%28*ptr1%5B3%5D%29%5B%5D). (and add that link to your bookmarks; its a most-handy tool).

Comment: See the comment: `// an array of 3 pointers to arrays of int`.  That's one of the bits that's really gruesome.  The `printf()` using it is the other part that's really gruesome.  It's enough to send an experienced C programmer running screaming!   Aaaaaaarrrrrrrrgggggghhhhhh!